# How to animate images in android in a loop?

Tags: android, animation

I have this xml file where there are 4 image views, with one logo at the centre and the other three are just circles with radius greater than the previous one surrounding the logo. I want to display this as an animation until my page gets loaded. In want that the three circles appear one after the other in loop in a sequence. How can I do that ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/anim1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/anim2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/anim3" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have also attached a picture for a better visualization if needed :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gw3i.png)

Comment: At first only show a single image (like the top image), after some pause show the second image and hide the first image, again after some pause show the last image, and hide the previous image. That's it.

Comment: @SkSuraj Yes.. but how to do that ?

Comment: Actually better practice is to use android animations. Read this tutorial to know more https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_animations.htm, hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Srijan,

There are more ways to achieve this. 
Please refer to objectAnimator or animation-list drawable for more details.

As a quick answer to your problem, please see the below sample code.

```
package com.jrh.testanim;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int count= 0;
int imgArr[] = new int[]{
        R.drawable.circle1,
        R.drawable.circle2,
        R.drawable.circle3,
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animation_imageview);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            imageView.setImageResource(imgArr[count]);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
            count++;
            if (count > 2) {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }, 500);

  }
}
```

Please check this and mark accepted, if it solves your problem.

Thanks
JRH